# Simple Truss Modeling Software

Tags: modeling, cad

I've a project in my university to create a bridge truss of straws, I am looking for a modeling software that can help me imagine my design's effectiveness (a software that's able to calculate the ratio between the weight of the truss and the load weight it can carry).

I've searched a lot, and I've only got advanced and complicated professional CAD tools and plugins, What I need is a simple offline/online software for that.